# Run javascript code in an HTML file using Java code

Tags: java, javascript, html

I want to be able to run javascript code in an HTML file using Java code. The HTML file is being downloaded using Java code but I am not able to run the Javascript code that should execute once the page is loaded and create new elements. Such as for:

```
<body onbeforeunload="unloadHandler1(event);" onUnload="unloadHandler();">
```

The function `unloadHandler1(event)` is meant to be run, but using Java code.

Comment: That's a pretty cranky question. What's this "Java code" you're talking about?

Answer (score 1):

I think that the OP wants to write his own browser in Java, or something like this.

The easy parts are

1. to download the page code using the `URL` class, and
2. to display the page using some rich text control, if it only consists of simple HTML code.

Unfortunately, everything else required to implement a browser is **not** straightforward.

In order to run the javascript contained in a page you need a full javascript interpreter (or similar tool); and the interpreter will probably have to interact with the HTML of the page (more accurately: the DOM) in order to modify it.

In the end, to fully interpret www pages you will need a *full browser engine*. If one exists in Java, you may use it...

Comment: Oh! it needs a FULL BROWSER ENGINE!! sorry i was not aware of it but thanks @nplatis for such a good explanation.
so let me come to u directly with my actual problem:
I want to develop a software to send SMS through way2sms, i found many a sample codes to do that but they were too old and are not working currently as the site has been upgraded, so i decided to program it myself. I found that Way2SMS gives a unique ID  like:

__gads=ID=de9da91f7eb487e...

to the application which is generated using Javascript after the page loads. I want to extract this ID to be able to send SMS.Is it possible?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know how to answer your question. But even if I knew, it would be better to post it as a new question, with a matching title and more concrete details.

Comment: Since you are new to this site, you should take into account that this is not a forum, but a site that values specific questions that lead to specific, useful answers. Moreover, if someone provides a good answer, you show your appreciation by "up-voting" his answer (click on the up arrow on the left of the answer -- I am not sure if you can do this yet). Also you should "accept" the best answer you receive in order to mark it as the one that solved your problem.